# React native device 'adb' not found

Tags: react-native, android-studio, emulation

I am trying to open my react native app on the android studio device emulator but I am facing an error :

**Couldn't start a project on Android: Error running adb: spawn emulator ENOENT
Error running adb: spawn emulator ENOENT**

Also, my emulator is in running condition. how to fix this
[image: error image]

Comment: What do you get when you run `react-native doctor` ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure code is working on web, then restart AVD. by closing it completely. mine is working now. but after some time whenever there is any error in code it crashes again and repeating the process makes it working. also before starting in AVD please close web testing.